# MYSQL Birthday Query

Tags: mysql

So im having troubles with my query, Its select the next three birthdays but say if some one birthday is on the April 12th. As soon as April 1st come along that birthday is no longer displayed.

```
SELECT `users`.`name`, 
       Date_format(`users_detail`.`dob_date`, '%d') AS day, 
       Date_format(`users_detail`.`dob_date`, '%M') AS month 
FROM   `users_detail` 
       JOIN `users` 
         ON `users`.`id` = `users_detail`.`id` 
WHERE  Date_add(`users_detail`.`dob_date`, 
              INTERVAL Year( Curdate() )- Year(`users_detail`.`dob_date`) + IF( 
              Dayofyear( 
              Curdate() ) >= Dayofyear(`users_detail`.`dob_date`), 1, 0 ) year) 
       BETWEEN Curdate() AND Date_add(Curdate(), INTERVAL 11 month) 
ORDER  BY `users_detail`.`dob_date` ASC 
LIMIT  3
```

Comment: You are trying to select the next 3 up coming birth days of your users ? In what format do you store `dob_date` column ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
SELECT `users`.`name`
FROM  `users_detail`
WHERE  DATE_ADD(`users_detail`.`dob_date`, 
                INTERVAL YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(`users_detail`.`dob_date`)
                         + IF(DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) > DAYOFYEAR(`users_detail`.`dob_date`),1,0)
                YEAR)  
            BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 month)
ORDER  BY `users_detail`.`dob_date` ASC 
LIMIT  3
```